# java.lang.NullPointerException:Invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

Estaba desarrollando una Aplicación Android utilizando Java, en la que implemento una BBDD con Firebase.

He implmentado la autenticación Google que es como me registro en un Login inicial que tiene la App, y en  el fragmento donde obtengo el error, es donde intento obtener los datos del usuario con el que autentico en Firebase.

Mi pregunta es que los métodos que implemtan las clases de Firebase deberían ser lo que hay que utilizar para obtener la información de usuario, entonces no tiene sentido que si autenticas con Google, y obtienes los datos estos sean nulos.

AcountFragment.fragment

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

    private AccountViewModel mViewModel;
    private EditText etUser;
    private Button btnLogOut;
    private Button btnChangePassWord;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public static AccountFragment newInstance() {
        return new AccountFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // init ViewModel
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(AccountViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        etUser = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EtUser);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        /*******tHIS LINE BELOW IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR************/
        mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Se ha producido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {

                    etUser.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

                    Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
                }
            }
        });

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getContext());

        btnLogOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);
        btnChangePassWord = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChangePass);

        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Cerramos Sesión.
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });

        btnChangePassWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             String email = etUser.getText().toString();

             if(email.isEmpty()){
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Debe ingresar el email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }else{

                 pDialog.setMessage("Espere mientras se realiza la operación...");
                 pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                 pDialog.show();


                 mAuth.setLanguageCode("es");
                 mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Se te acaba de inviar un correo para restablecer tu contraseña.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No se ha podido restablecer la contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        //Oculto el diolog cuando termine la tarea.
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                     }
                 });

             }


            }
        });

        mViewModel.getName().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                etUser.setText(s);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AccountViewModel.class);

    }

}
```

If you can help take thanks for advance!

Comment: [Revisa los ejemplos de la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?hl=es#access_user_information)  y más cosas que allí se explican. En cualquier caso deberías verificar primero si el usuario se ha autentificado, cosa que parece no estar ocurriendo. Si eso no ocurre tienes que ver por qué.

Comment: Es imposible que no este ocurriendo porque sino no pasaría de la pantalla del login

Comment: ¿Tienes un NPE ante tus ojos y dices que es imposible? Revisa la doc, está claramente indicado que deberías controlar que no es nulo. ¿Qué tal si las credenciales son incorrectas por ejemplo, o la autentificación falla por cualquier otro motivo? No puedes en ningún caso pasar a usar un objeto sin comprobar primero que no es nulo, porque pasa justamente lo que ocurre ahora, que tienes un NPE.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia pero que es un NPE?

Comment: Null Pointer Exception, el error cuando algún objeto es nulo. Prueba a poner un `if` más o menos así: `if (mAuth != null) { //Aqui el código } else { //aquí decidir que hacer si es nulo}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que mAuth.getCurrentUser() es null, puedes chequear ese valor antes de pedir el UID

```
if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()
}
```

Comment: He probado a implementar tu solución, efectivamente entra en el else, por lo que efectivamente no hay ningun usuario registrado, pero porque, si autentico con Google??